# how to pass json data as an input in proxy using sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

is there any way to pass `json` as an input to `proxy` for the input for webservices url

just the way we do in `Ext.Ajax` using `jsonData` parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

The proxy accepts an object like this:
      proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://google.com',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            },
            autoLoad: 'true'
        }

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax proxy defines an extraParams config:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-extraParams

Addtionally, if you are using a store, see the comments on the load function:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load